# finding mode from histogram

Tags: c, structure, histogram, mode

i have this function to print the histogram, I suppose to use this function calculate mode as well, I understand that to find mode you need to compare number of occurrences of each score, but I can't figured out how to implement this into the code. Is there anyway to implement this function to find mode?

this is my function

```
int calMode(RECORD list[], int count){
int tempMode = 0;
int i, k;
int current = 0;

while (current < count)
{
    printf("%d:", list[current].score);
    for(k=0; (i=current + k) < count ; ++k)
   {
        if(list[current].score == list[i].score)
            printf("*");
        else
            break;
    }
      if(k > tempMode)
        tempMode = k;
    printf("\n");
    current = current + k;
}
printf("%d\n", tempMode);
   return tempMode;
}
```

Comment: I think to compare it to how the values ​​that you save as max simply if you just find the maximum value of `k`. However, if the maximum values ​​are the same.

Comment: "*Is there anyway to implement this function to find mode?*" Yes. Do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int calMode(RECORD list[], int count){
    int tempMode;
    int i, k;
    int current = 0;
    int max = -1;
    int update = 0;

    while (current < count){
        printf("%d:", list[current].score);
        for(k=0; (i=current + k) < count ; ++k){
            if(list[current].score == list[i].score)
                printf("*");
            else
                break;
        }
        printf("\n");

        if(k>max){
            max = k;
            tempMode = list[current].score;
            update  = 1;
        } else if(k == max){
            update = 0;
        }

        current = current + k;
    }
    if(update == 0)
        tempMode = -1;//indeterminable
    return tempMode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need a different algorithm. You need to find the maximum `.score` member of your items, and store the corresponding index(es). Something like this might do:

```
int max = list[0].score;
RECORD *max_item[count] = { &list[0] };
size_t index = 1;
while (count-- > 1) {
    // We're looking for any items that are greater than or equal to the
    // current max, so when we find items that are less, we jump back to
    // the condition evaluation using "continue".
    if (list[count].score < max) { continue; }

    // When we find a value that's greater than the current maximum, we
    // need to discard all previously stored "maximum" items and update
    // our current maximum.
    if (list[count].score > max) {
        index = 0;
        max = list[count].score;
    }

    // At this point, the current item can't be less than the current max.
    // This is because of the "continue;" earlier. Add this item to our
    // list of "maximum" items.
    max_item[index++] = &list[count];
}
```

`max` now stores the maximum score in your histogram, `index` stores the number of items that contain that maximum score and `max_item` stores pointers to `RECORD`s that contain that item.